# How to add conditional validators in formBuilder Angular

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular 7.x using the formBuilder and ReactiveForms, I am trying to put a validator to a form which is based on the role the user has. So when the user has a different `role`, he/she is required to put in a field. I store this user in a variable stored in the class.

I don't want to put the validator on the subscription of valueChange but on the initial build. How am I able to do so? Below some code.

```
 buildForm(): void {
    this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
      initials: [this.user.initials, Validators.required],
      lastNamePrefix: [this.user.lastNamePrefix],
      lastName: [this.user.lastName, Validators.required],
      cellPhoneNumber: [this.user.cellPhoneNumber], <-- make this one required if the role of the user is x
      ]),
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can write a custom validator for it and add it to cellPhoneNumber array

Comment: This might help you: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators

Comment: can the role of the user change after the validator is setted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the role of the user does not change once the validator is setted, an approach would be the following:

```
import {ValidatorFn, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

function createCellPhoneValidator(user: FooUser): ValidatorFn {
  return user.role === x ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator;
}

export class FooComponent {
  buildForm(): void {
    this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
      initials: [this.user.initials, Validators.required],
      lastNamePrefix: [this.user.lastNamePrefix],
      lastName: [this.user.lastName, Validators.required],
      cellPhoneNumber: [this.user.cellPhoneNumber, createCellPhoneValidator(this.user)],
    });
  }
}
```

If the role can change, then you would need to re-evaluate the role every time before performing the validation. This could be done as:

```
import {ValidatorFn, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

export class FooComponent {
  buildForm(): void {
    this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
      initials: [this.user.initials, Validators.required],
      lastNamePrefix: [this.user.lastNamePrefix],
      lastName: [this.user.lastName, Validators.required],
      cellPhoneNumber: [this.user.cellPhoneNumber, this.cellPhoneValidator],
    });
  }

  private readonly cellPhoneValidator: ValidatorFn = c => {
     return this.user.role === "x" ? Validators.required(c) : Validators.nullValidator(c);
   }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks jota! I couldn't answer your other question in time but you already provided the a solution for that scenario.